# PHP ajax post still print out previous message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, class

I have a page use ajax post and send message back

```
if( $_GET['foo'] == FALSE ){
    die("u must tick foo");
}

//if $_GET['foo'] pass
die("<script>location.reload();</script>");
```

My problem is
When user post first time, if user didn't click button and foo is FALSE
, script die and output message

But if user tick button and post it again, page did pass `if()` and do `location.reload`

but somehow it still print out the message "u must tick.." before `location.reload`

by the way its inside of class public function

Comment: _but somehow it still print out the message "u must tick.."_ This unusual behavior may be caused by your condition expression. I'm not sure why `die()` doesn't exit processing script, maybe because the script loaded twice? Anyways, why don't you use `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isset` to check whether that GET is defined

```
if( isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == FALSE ){
    die("u must tick foo");
}

//if $_GET['foo'] pass
die("<script>location.reload();</script>");
```

Comment: isset is not the problem, its just an example, i did check everything before, my question is 2nd time foo is TRUE why it still print out the message than do location.reload

Comment: If you reverse you condition will it work like:
if(isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == 'something') {
  die("<script>location.reload();</script>");
}else{
  die("u must tick foo");
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use '===' instead of '==' for if().
And 'if else' may be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the brower is caching your request. To prevent this, you will have to disable browser caching by sending these headers at the top of your php script:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache,max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

*Note:* clear your browser cache before testing it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some timestamp to your request to avoid caches.

Assuming that you're sending something like `"http://www.example.com/index.php?foo=false"`, you can try with something like this `"http://www.example.com/index.php?foo=false&_="+(new Date())`

Anyway, notice that you won't receive nothing that can be compared with `FALSE` if you're not sending `"0"` or `""`. `"false"` as a string is `true` in PHP.